# BCD consideraton, does it matter?

Tags: crankset

I currently have a Shimano 5700 10 speed double 53-39 t crankset with BCD of 130 mm (http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/shimano-105-5700-double-10sp-chainset/rp-prod50439?gs=1&gclid=Cj0KEQiA-NqyBRC905irsrLr-LUBEiQAWJFYTkxMA9a_E1fL6-t7-aTW19bkJuJg-JSW1YW7l4VlWooaAuNz8P8HAQ&gclsrc=aw.ds).

Can I change to a Shimano 110 mm BCD cranks of 53-39 t (http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/shimano-105-5800-11-speed-double-chainset/rp-prod116491)? That's 11 speed but I don't think that will matter. The reason to change is I want to try a 165 mm length crank instead of 170 mm on current.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The BCD shouldn't make any difference to how the cranks work, just which chainrings you use. As long as the BB matches the cranks go ahead.